# Move form element outside the form, and place it inside another div

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a sidebar on my page with search/filter form. What I trying to do is to move one of the elements (sort order dropdown) from this form, outside the form with CSS/JS and display it inside div on the right side. Is it possible without loosing form functionallity? Please chcek my code:

```
<div class="left-sidebar">
  <form>
    <div class="move-this-outside">Dropdown is here</div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="sort-order-container">Here i need to drop it</div>
</div>
```

Of course I can use `position:absolute;` but how to make this dropdown relative to another div outside the form? Page content is flexible (pagination, banners etc.). It has to be physically inside the `<form></form>` to work, but I need to display (simulate display) it inside another div.

Comment: you can associate a form element with a particular form using the [form attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform)

Comment: But I don't have access to modify html in this case.

Comment: Huh? Why not? You can modify the CSS but not the HTML? That's a weird situation and really doesn't make much sense...you're either developing the application or you're not. You can't change HTML/JS/CSS in isolation, they are interdependent, especially the HTML and CSS. If you don't have access to make changes then the question is pointless.

Comment: I mean I guess you _could_ use some JS to move it after the page has loaded, and add the form attribute to it, but that's a ridiculous workaround and should not be necessary. Just change the HTML. If you're not allowed to for some strange reason, then get the person who's in charge of it to change it.

Comment: Filtering form is a WordPress plugin, and I can't modify this part.

Comment: If you installed the plugin in your site then you have access to the source code, it will be there in your installed files. I agree you might not be keen to make modifications in case it breaks something or makes the plugin unsupported, but you do have that possibility in practice. You need to make a choice.

Comment: Yes but I can't modify that. Plugin is a form creator (https://searchandfilter.com/) and output html is not static. Support says they working on update to let users combine forms. At this moment I need to find walkaround. I was trying .appendTo() in JS but it moves <select> outside the form and then it not working. From all ideas position:absolute, and negative numbers looks the best but it is not best way with RWD websites, hard to find best position.

Comment: `it moves <select> outside the form and then it not working.`...because you also need to set the form attribute on it (as mentioned in the first comment) when you do that, so it's still associated with the form. And for that to work, you also need to give the form an ID to identify it. All that is possible with JavaScript. It's a bit harder though if the HTML structure is not predictable in advance.

Comment: Yes I know. I could try .appendTo() + add form attribute, but can I add form="my-form-id" using JS?

Comment: Yes. It is just an attribute...JS can set attributes on any element. The ID of an element is also an attribute you can set.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are able to run Javascript without the same restrictions as with the editing of the HTML for the form then some very simple Javascript like this should suffice to move the `select` menu to the new location.

I put the relevant code within the `setTimeout` only so that the `move` is observable.

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  /* identify the various HTML elements needed in the move process */
  let form=document.querySelector('.left-sidebar > form');
  let target=document.querySelector('.page-content > .sort-order-container');

  /* Move the Select from original location (sidebar) to the new location */
  target.appendChild( form.querySelector('.move-this-outside') );

  /* set the ID of the form and associate the select with that form by ID */
  form.setAttribute('id','filter');
  target.firstElementChild.querySelector('select').setAttribute('form','filter');
},2500);
```

```css
/*
  To show the select has moved
*/
.left-sidebar{border:1px solid red;}
.page-content{border:1px solid black;}
.sort-order-container{border:1px solid blue;}
select{background:pink}
h1{font-size:1.1rem}
*{padding:0.25rem;margin:0.25rem auto}
```

```html
<div class="left-sidebar">
  <form>
    <h1>Select Menu was here</h1>
    <!-- source -->
    <div class="move-this-outside">
      <select>
        <option>Hello World
        <option>Goodbye World
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--

  other html content perhaps

-->
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="sort-order-container">
  <!-- target -->
  </div>
</div>
```